# Analyst Estimates for Earnings on the S&P 500

Tags: data-request, finance

I'm looking for free and open-source Analyst Estimates for the S&P 500.  If the name of the Analyst was include that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with this crowd-sourced project, but they claim to be crowd sourcing estimated earnings:

https://www.estimize.com/

Their tagline is: 
The Most Comprehensive Earnings Forecasts
Crowdsourced estimates from over 4,500 hedge fund, brokerage, and independent analysts

According to Crunchbase, they are Venture funded.

Funding Received $2.6 Million in 3 Rounds from 8 InvestorsMost
Recent Funding$1.2 Million Series A on March 26, 2014
Headquarters:New York, NY
Description:Estimize is an open financial estimates platform which facilitates the aggregation of fundamental estimates from independent analysts.
Founders:Matthew Jording, Leigh Drogen
Categories:Crowdsourcing,

Comment: What a great idea.  Thank you for the information.  It would be great if they could get non professional to vote in someway too.  I tend to think too much bias is in the earnings estimates... since most people who do this work have a horse in the race in someway or another.  Not that I'm suggesting that anyone push the number one way for their benefit just that it hard to be objective.

Answer (score 0):

This is very commercially valuable data. I'm skeptical you will find a free source. Who would be motivated to gather it and give it away?

Comment: not to be rude, but your opinion is merely your opinion. there are billions of other opinions on the planet...i'm sure one is contrary

Comment: Kinda rude, yeah. The fact that you can find contrary opinions doesn't make all opinions correct.

Comment: more to the point, I'm a little frustrated with the number of essentially unanswerable questions that are backing up in the "unanswered" queue on this SE site. It makes it harder to look for new unanswered questions which actually have answers. Maybe it wasn't worth bothering to give my answer above, but I do think people should have a clear-eyed perspective on "free open sources" for data.

Comment: i applaud your effort, and i agree mostly. just wanted to make the point that what you don't see as valuable someone else can and will